# Web application: managing users database access

Tags: database, web-applications, permissions

I'd like to know what the best way to keep the different users' database accesses under control is. Since I'm implementing the common scenario of making users login to the app before accessing certain pages, I thought that it would be also nice to restrict the database access to only the data each user needs to see by creating views and new users at database-level granted just certain permissions. Those database users will have the same usernames that those users have for accessing the app, and so, when users are loging in, I could access the database with the username they are providing on the application form... Is this the correct way to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: So you would have a database user with grant permissions that would be used by visitors who are not logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of a web application, the common practice is rather to have a pool of connections with a unique user.
Each request uses an already open connection from this pool. This way you'll get much better performances. (connections already open, cache of the prepared statements, ...)

As for which data the users should have access to or not, this should be coded in the service layer of the application, not in the database (in the web-application culture, I would say).

Moreover, the system you describe will be a pain to maintain proper synchro between application users and database users.